# I need to add all the screenshots of steps performed in One word file using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Please help me out.

I want to add all the steps screenshot in one document(word) file using selenium webdriver with java for that particular test case and that file should get stored with a that particular test case name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFRun run = docx.createParagraph().createRun();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Result\\Screenshot");

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) {
            captureScreenShot(docx, run, out);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }

        docx.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        docx.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void captureScreenShot(XWPFDocument docx, XWPFRun run, FileOutputStream out) throws Exception {

    String screenshot_name = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
    BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Result\\Screenshot" + screenshot_name);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
    InputStream pic = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Result\\Screenshot" + screenshot_name);
    run.addBreak();
    run.addPicture(pic, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, screenshot_name, Units.toEMU(350), Units.toEMU(350));
    pic.close();
    file.delete();
}
```

Comment: What are your efforts in trying to solve this problem?

Comment: Please check the above code

Comment: Its taking blank screenshot and that too not in word document. simple .png format

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: its not taking any screenshot neither its creating any doc file